# Por que foi que «ir» e «ser» ficaram iguais no Pretérito Perfeito? Why are "ir" and "ser" the same in the preterite?

Tags: etimologia, conjugações

Uma curiosidade que o português tem em comum com o castelhano é que o Pretérito Perfeito dos verbos *ser* e *ir* são iguais, quanto na escritura e na pronúncia: *fui, foste, foi, fomos, fostes, foram* (no português). Mas *foi* de *ir* e *foi* de *ser* não têm o mesmo significado, não é?

Como é que isto aconteceu?

---

Something I've always found odd in Portuguese and Spanish is that the preterite forms of *ser* and *ir* are spelled and pronounced the same: *fui, foste, foi, fomos, fostes, foram* (in Portuguese). But they don't have the same meaning, right?

How did this come to be?

Comment: De es.se: [¿Cómo han evolucionado los verbos "ser" e "ir" para tener la misma conjugación en el pretérito?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/220/457) That doesn't “answer” the question, though, and the answer there is mostly just restating the question. There may be some connection to how there can be no confusion in Portuguese (or Spanish) the way there would be in English. Start out with “I went there” using *ir*. Now if you swap in the “I was” sense, as in “I was there”, you **have** to use *estar* for that, not *ser*. So *ser* and *ir* never conflict. Unclear how that connects though.

Comment: @tchrist yeah, that explains where it came from, making perfect sense for *ser*, and why there wasn't pressure for it to change, but it leaves a big open question of why *esse* would be used for *ir* in the preterite.

Comment: Ali says _ir_ was complemented with forms from _ser_ (actually _seer_ meaning _ser_, but also _estar_ and _estar sentado_). He even distinguishes between _seer_ coming _esse_ (giving today's _ser_) and _seer_ coming from _sedere_ (now extinct), though [Carolina Michaëlis describes](http://www.letras.puc-rio.br/unidades&nucleos/catedra/revista/9Sem_02.html) a _seer_ originally from _sedere_ that progressively loses forms from _sedere_. I've also seen the theory that _fui_ (arch. _foi_ / _foy_), etc. came from _fugere_ (that also gave _fugir_).

Comment: @Artefacto Who's Ali?

Comment: @DanGetz [Manuel Said Ali Ida](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_Said_Ali_Ida), grande filólogo brasileiro.

Comment: And why *ser* and *estar* are both *to be* (en), *être* (fr) and *sein* (de)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A resposta é porque "ser" e "ir", entre outros verbos, são verbos **polirrizos**, é dizer, verbos com várias raízes, o "be" em inglês também é, e em todas as línguas **indoeuropéias** podemos encontrar o fenômeno, e tudo foi resultado da mistura no latim vulgar.

---

*Ser*, vem do verbo latim *esse* que originalmente significa existir, mas que eventualmente, no latim mesmo, foi mudando o significado, lembrando que as línguas indoeuropeias podem ser rastreadas muito antes de existir o império romano e so existem um par de línguas não indoeuropeias na Europa, por exemplo, o euskera.

*Esse* do latim, tem sua origem no verbo indoeuropeio *es-* ou simplesmente *s-*, conjudado seria:

| Indoeuropeio | Grego | Latim | Português |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| es-mi | eimi | sum | sou |
| es-se | essi | es | és |
| es-ti | esti | est | é |
| es-mes | eimen | sumus | somos |
| es-thé | este | estis | sois |
| es-nti | eisi | sunt | são |

Analogamente "ir" tem sua raiz no "eo-" indoeuropeio.

---

Agora o interessante e onde cruza-se tudo, no latim existe (ou existia) o verbo *fieri*, que tem sua raiz no *fu-* ou *bhu-* *indoeuropeio*. Alguma semelhança do *bhu-* com o *be* ou *been* inglês? ;). *fieri* vem a significar "chegar a ser", por isso os conjuntivos em futuro de ser e ir têm sua origem em *fu-* e não nem em *es-* nem em *eo-*.

---

E finalmente no caso do ir, ele competia com o verbo *vadere* em latim, que vem a significar marchar ou avançar, *vadere* ganhou do *ire* no latim vulgar, porque ir se prestava a cofunções, por causa dos sotaques por exemplo. Mais ou menos como acontece quando alguém prefere usar observar em lugar de ver, colocar em lugar de por, ou escutar em lugar de ouvir, entre algum dos muitos exemplos.

---

E assim aconteceu.

Comment: Legal né? Eventualmente procurarei e colocarei referências em português, mas por enquanto não tenho.

Comment: Muito interessante. Está a dizer que *fieri* foi raiz de *ir* no conjuntivo em futuro porque o sentido de "chegar a ser" é parecido com "chegar" mesmo? Mas ainda não abordou o pretérito. Aconteceu da mesma maneira?

Comment: não, é parecido porque já no latim vulgar tinha adquirido esse uso, assim como no latim esse adquiriu o como estado, observa as diferenças enter vita est in terra o significado original de existir, vida existe na terra, e iulius altus est, Julio alto existe ou Julio alto é. o de como fieri pasou a ser raiz de ir não sei explicar, mas aconteceu assim, lembrando que foi na latim vulgar, assim como, por exemplo, constranger passou a significar coagir mas do que apertar.

Comment: A resposta do pretérito é, porque ir e ser são verbos polirrizos ou com mais de uma raiz (indoeuropeia no caso), sendo que compartem uma das raízes, bheu-. depois melhoro a resposta, com mais tempo.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple: they were the same in Latin, already.  Portuguese and Spanish simply inherited this irregularity.  Back then, they used the same forms for both verbs, but with different senses, just as it is today in Portuguese and Spanish.

Usually if you're unsure, try to replace the verb by the corresponding form in the simple present: almost always only one of them will make sense.  You should fairly quickly get a sense for which verb it is without having to think about it, though.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that they have different senses today. But could you explain in more detail what you mean by "the same in Latin"? Very similar conjugations can be seen in the Classical Latin verb *esse*, which Wiktionary tells me meant "to be", "to exist", or in some circumstances "to have X-ed". Classical Latin had a verb *ire*, but it was conjugated differently—no "f" to be seen. So in Classical Latin, they seem to have been different. And from what I've found so far, Romance languages from outside Iberia don't have this same conjugation.

Comment: São verbos com mais de uma raiz, lembro que num batepapo de bar com um profesor de literatura (em espanhol) ele me explicou que a origem é muito além do latim, de aqui a pouco procuro algo em que basearme para reponder.