# Verbos "ir" e "ser"

Tags: verbos, origem-histórica, conjugações

Por que as conjugações dos verbos *ir* e *ser* coincidem no pretérito perfeito do indicativo (*fui, fomos*, etc) e no pretérito do subjuntivo (*fosse, fôssemos*, etc)?

Suponho que esses dois verbos tinham conjugações regulares (em latim, talvez?) e, com o tempo, alguns tempos convergiram. Como isso aconteceu?

Comment: Perguntei (quase) o mesmo [aqui](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1853/112), mas ainda está sem resposta completa.

Answer (score 6):

Um professor de português, professor Kaiser, disse que estes verbos são formados pela unificação de 3 verbos do latim, cada um. Estes verbos latinos não continham todas as pessoas (defectivos). Logo, estes verbos se tornaram anómalos em português por conter radicais diferentes em suas conjugações.

Segue um texto retirado do site [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-radical-dos-verbos-ser-e-ir/24203):

> O radical é o constituinte da palavra com significado lexical que não inclui afixos de flexão, mas que pode incluir afixos derivacionais. Os verbos irregulares afastam-se do modelo de conjugação dos verbos regulares, apresentando alterações no radical e/ou nas suas desinências. Os verbos **ser** e **ir** são verbos muito irregulares, ou seja, têm uma flexão com diferentes radicais.
>
> O verbo **ser** tem origem nos verbos latinos *esse* e *sedere*, e por isso apresenta radicais diferentes em formas como **s-** (**somos, sou**), **er-** (**era**) e com **f-** (**fui, fora**), que assentam no verbo latino esse, bem como **se-**, de *sedere* (**seja, serei** ou **seria**).
>
> A flexão do verbo **ir** tem por base o fenómeno denominado supletivismo verbal, uma vez que provém de três verbos latinos diferentes apresentando formas com os radicais: *ire* (**ia, irei, iria, indo, ido**), *vadere* (**vou, vais, vai, vamos, vão; vá, vás, vades**) e **fu-** (radical do sistema do perfeito do verbo *esse*, «ser» — **fui, fora, fosse**, etc.).